The existence of a measure $\mu $ on [0,1] such that $\int pd\mu =\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}p^{(k)}(k/n)$?
How to show the existence of a measure $\mu $ on [0,1] such that for every polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$, $\int pd\mu =\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}p^{(k)}(k/n)$.

Hint Let $V$ be the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ equipped with the inner product $\langle p,q\rangle=\int_{[0,1]}p(x)q(x),\mathrm{d}x$. Then there exists a dual basis ${e_0(x),\ldots,e_n(x)}$ of ${1,x,\ldots,x^n}$ such that $$\langle x^i,e_j(x)\rangle=\delta_{ij}.$$

Since $0 \le x^k \le 1$ for $x \in [0,1]$ then $0 \le  \int x^k d \mu  \le 0$.

I don't get the breakneck rush to close.

@SangchulLee Could you please describe it in more detail?

Presumably you are looking for a signed measure that satisfies the conditions, because no positive measure can be found that meets the conditions.

Let $e_0(x), \ldots, e_n(x)$ be the polynomials such that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} e_i(x) x^j \, \mathrm{d}x = \delta_{ij} $$
for each $i, j = 0, \ldots, n$. (The existence and uniqueness of such $\{e_i\}_{i=0}^{n}$ comes from those of the dual basis and the Riesz representation theorem. More concretely, the coefficients of $e_i$'s can be explicitly written using Hilbert matrix, although this is not needed in this proof.)
Now note that, for $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i$,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} p^{(k)}(k/n)
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=k}^{n} a_i \frac{i!}{(i-k)!} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{i-k}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i a_i $$
for $c_i = \sum_{k=1}^{i} \frac{i!}{(i-k)!} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{i-k}$. Hence, using $e_i$'s,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} p^{(k)}(k/n)
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \int_{0}^{1} e_i(x) p(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i e_i(x) \right] p(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
$$
This proves that we can choose:
$$ \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i e_i(x) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Thanks a lot, but can you explain how to use Riesz representation theorem and dual basis to show that the existence and uniqueness of such ${e_i}_{i=0}^n$

@Peter, It is well-known from linear algebra that, for each basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, there is a unique corresponding dual basis $\mathfrak{B}^$ of the dual vector space $V^$. Now, if $V$ is also an inner product space, Riesz representation theorem allows identifying $V^$ with $V$, which then allows identifying $\mathfrak{B}^$ as another basis of $V$.
